# Replica configuration - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

On mongo 3.2.17 I have the following output when running rs.initiate(). I need "ok" equal to 1. I don't know how to modified the configuration. Any suggestion?

```
{
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for 
the set",
    "me" : "vpsxxxxxx:27017",
    "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current 
configuration",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "already initialized",
    "code" : 23
}
```

Comment: The error message suggests that your `mongod` has data files with an existing replica set configuration. Since a replica set can only be initiated once, this would be an expected error. You can check for existing configuration in the `mongo` shell using: `db.getSiblingDB('local').system.replset.findOne()`. What is the provenance of the data in your `dbPath` ? For example: is this a fresh install, an upgrade from a standalone, an attempt to restore from backup, or some other scenario?

Comment: I have reinstalled mongodb, now when I run `mongo` I get `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10` and when I run in the shell `rs.initiate()` I get `"ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "server is not running with --replSet"` What I can do? I am completely lost. How I can start again from zero?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have already initialized replication on your machine. This would work on a fresh instance. In your case try using **reconfig** instead of **initiate**

```
rs.reconfig(config, {force: true})
```

You can use force option when reconfiguring replica set. Make sure you have at least 3 nodes: 2 full nodes and 1 arbiter (minimum supported configuration) or 3 full nodes (minimum recommended configuration) so that primary node can be elected.